# How to create custom annotation for StoredProcedure and Column in spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to creat custom annotations for StoredProcedure & Column.
Example:
@StoredProcedure with three parameters like query,structname,structArrayName
and @Column with have five fields like name, postion, type, required.

Can anybody help me how create it and apply in entity class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can add meta-annotations to specify the scope and the target of our custom annotation.
Ex:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE) 
public @interface StoredProcedure {
    String query ();
    String structName ();
    String structArrayName ();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) 
public @interface Column {
    
    public String name();
    public int position ();
    public String datePattern () default "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
    public String defValue () default "";
    public boolean required () default false;
    public String actualType () default "na";
}

// we can apply annotations in class level and field level.
@StoredProcedure(query = "{}", structName = "", structArrayName = "")
public class Data {

    @Column(name = "id", position = 1, actualType = "string", required = true)
    @Validate(length = )
    public String id;

    @Column(name = "name", position = 2, actualType = "number")
    @Validate(length = )
    public Long name;
}
```